# Is there a way to alter the edges of a step line chart in chartjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am currently attempting to alter a chart in chartjs which is a step line chart. Currently the edges are very jagged, as they are a perfect 90 degrees. What I want to achieve is a slight radius to smoothen the edges out, so there is a bit more flow. I have not really found any suggestions nor plugins to alter a charts edges, so does anyone have any possible solutions?

The current stack im in uses react with typescript.

This is what I wish to achieve:

[image]

Thanks in advance!